# How do I make a 6v DC motor charge a phone battery via 5v, 2amp

Tags: motor, 5v, conversion

I am a high school student who knows absolutely zero about electrical engineering (I may have even misworded the question), and I am interested in how I could connect a small motor (as in putting a hand crank on it) to a use port to charge say a phone or tablet. I have found ports online that say they handle 5v, so I assume that is what I need to adapt to, however I have only found small dc motors in 3, 6, 9, and 12v. I assume that the 6v would be best since it is the closest to 5v. I could most definitely be wrong, but do I need some sort of converter, diode, adaptor, or regulator?

P.S. Please explain because I do not know what any of those are.

Comment: try spinning the motor into a DVM on a cordless drill Your DVM reading wont be 5v but volts is proportional to speed so you are in the ball park because you know roughly your speed

Comment: if a motor is 6V at 1000 rpm for example, if you were to rig up a system to crank it manually at 1000rpm (using gears, usually) you will see 6V over the coils, and a certain amount of current being produced as well. You should measure all of this, to work out how much you can actually get out of it. This would be using the motor as a "generator". You will probably need a 5V linear regulator and an undervoltage lock-out circuit, to ensure that the generator has reached the correct output and will charge the output device.

Comment: Okay awesome I appreciate it! So, say, if you took that same 6v motor and cranked it at around 850 RPM, would you get 5v? I don't know if it works that way or not. What do the regulator and lock out circuit do? And would it still charge at any rpm or just when it reaches the certain rpm? Thanks much!

Comment: when it reaches a certain rpm

Comment: if you dont do the under voltage lockout the regulator may begin regulating but put out less than 5v which is not good

Answer (score 1):

The motor will produce voltage according to the RPM it is spun at. The easiest way without a lot of measurement tools to get the appropriate voltage is to find the Kv rating of the motor. Kv (k meaning "motor constant", v meaning "velocity") is what RPM the motor turns at per volt applied. For instance, if you have a 1,000kv rated motor, you need to spin it at 4200RPM to produce ~4.2v. You obviously can't spin at this rate by hand (maybe you can, I don't know you!), so you'd need a reduction drive to couple a crank with the shaft.

Most off the eBay shelf battery to USB DC converters are boost converters designed to step up the 4.2v from a lithium cell to 5v. So if you were to procure one of these USB DC converters, you could wire it onto your motor along with a little LCD voltimeter, and turn it just fast enough to maintain the voltage between 3-4.2v.

Comment: Also, don't start the test using your phone! Perhaps use something less expensive to prove your concept :p

Comment: Keep in mind that a common lithium phone battery can be as large as 3900 milliamp hours, like the Droid Turbo. That means you'll have to crank for 2 hours or more to charge that battery fully!

Comment: The crank was just an example!! :D just wanting to exemplify what I'm trying to accomplish :)

Comment: So what I'm looking for is something that I can turn at basically any rate (within realistic limits), and still get it charging at some rate depending on the rpm. Would this still work with the converter you mentioned? If so, could you provide a link to what you are referring to so that I male sure I get my hands on the correct thing?

Comment: Also, how do I make sure I have the correct amperage? I think phones charge at 1 amp and tablets around 2 ish?

Comment: Sorry for all the questions,  but say if your rpm's were to exceed the 6v for the motor, would it fry the phone?

Comment: The amperage component is the resistance you'll feel while turning at a given RPM. If you put a device on it that can pull 2 amps, you'll feel more resistance and also be supplying 2 amps. In fact, you could put something on the other side that needs 20 amps. You'd likely burn the motor up at a load that high, but it would work for a few moments.

Comment: If you were to increase the voltage past the rated voltage of the motor, you would likely end up damaging the motor, and probably end up ruining the DC converter that is changing the voltage from the motor into a usable USB 5v.

Comment: If you want something you can turn at any rate and output the voltage you need, you'll need a buck-boost converter. This is a type of DC converter that will either lower or increase the output voltage of the source into a set voltage, like 5v.

Comment: I'd start learning about Ohm's law, a very simple law that shows the relationship between voltage, current, and resistance, and how they each play an incredibly important part in supplying power to anything.